# libreoffice replace paragraph breaks

Tags: libreoffice

I have a songbook, but at the end of each line, there is a paragraph break. Any song, that exceeds one page gets split up somewhere in the middle of a verse. I could manually fix each song, there is not that many of them which are that long, but then I would not be able to for example change font size, without messing it all up again. I need to replace all single paragraph breaks with line breaks, but leave all groups of two or more paragraph breaks and all page breaks be. I tried Replacing all paragraph breaks, but that just messes my formating up so much, that it would be easier to manualy replace all of them (for some reason it took all the pagebreaks as well).

Comment: What you've exactly tried?

Comment: copy linebreak, search and replace with regex enabled, searched for $, find all, ctrl + v